# Upgrading Symfony project from 3.2 to 3.4

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.2, symfony-3.4

I am trying to upgrade Symfony on Windows 10 machine. Current version is 3.2. I've updated the `composer.json` package to `"symfony/symfony": "3.4.*"`. Then I ran `composer update symfony/symfony` and got the following error message:

```
The requested package symfony/symfony 3.4.* exists as symfony/symfony[v3.2.2] but these are rejected by your constraint.
```

Any ideas what can be the problem? Thanks!

Here is the `composer.json` file:

```
{
    "name": "martin/editor",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "type": "project",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "": "src/"
        },
        "classmap": [
            "app/AppKernel.php",
            "app/AppCache.php"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
        "symfony/symfony": "3.4.*",
        "doctrine/orm": "^2.5",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^1.6",
        "doctrine/doctrine-cache-bundle": "^1.2",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^2.3.10",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.0.2",
        "symfony/polyfill-apcu": "^1.0",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "^5.0",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^3.0.2",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "^2.0",
        "mikehaertl/php-shellcommand": ">=1.2.4",
        "phpoffice/phpspreadsheet": "*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "^3.0",
        "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "^3.0"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "symfony-scripts": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "@symfony-scripts"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@symfony-scripts"
        ]
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony-app-dir": "app",
        "symfony-bin-dir": "bin",
        "symfony-var-dir": "var",
        "symfony-web-dir": "web",
        "symfony-tests-dir": "tests",
        "symfony-assets-install": "relative",
        "incenteev-parameters": {
            "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
        },
        "branch-alias": null
    },
    "repositories": [{
        "type": "composer",
        "url": "https:\/\/www.phpclasses.org\/"
    }, {
        "packagist": false
    }, {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "https://github.com/mikehaertl/php-shellcommand"
    }, {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet"
    }, {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "https://github.com/php-fig/simple-cache"
    }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Maybe the php version?  Try installing the symfony skeleton as a new project and see what happens.

Comment: The PHP version is 5.6.31 so I guess somewhere else is the problem.

Comment: Please show your composer.json file

Comment: @FranckGamess Done. Thanks for looking at this!

Comment: @Martin Dimitrov try to replace 3.4.* by ~3.2 then execute composer update. Because ~3.2 is equivalent to >=3.2 <4.0.0 so it should match 3.4.latest. If it works you will be able to put 3.4.*

Comment: @FranckGamess I did as you suggested but composer didn't update anything :( `Nothing to install or update`

Comment: ok @Martin Dimitrov, try this one ^3.2.2. If none of them work, you can try two hard ways to update: 1)removing composer.lock and vendor folder and run the command again. 2) run the command using --ignore-platform-reqs composer option just for this time

Comment: @FranckGamess Thanks for all your suggestions but none of them worked! Something apparently is very messy with the composer/symfony setup.

Comment: Please try `composer update symfony/symfony --with-dependencies`